# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'length') in Nextjs error

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am getting such an error in nextjs files:

```
  117 |   };
  118 | 
> 119 |   if (data.length <= 0) {
      |           ^
  120 |     return null;
  121 |   }
  122 |
```

if I want to show it with a photo, it is as follows:[image]

The project works on different computers, but it doesn't work on me. How do I fix this error?
[image]

i also encounter different errors every time I refresh the page.
[image]

```
17354 |     ReactCurrentOwner$1.current = workInProgress;
  17355 |     setIsRendering(true);
> 17356 |     nextChildren = renderWithHooks(current, workInProgress, Component, nextProps, context, renderLanes);
  17357 | 
  17358 |     if ( workInProgress.mode & StrictMode) {
  17359 |       disableLogs();
```

Comment: Could you try checking ```data``` is defined first by using  ```if (data && data.length <= 0) { ... }``` .

Answer (score 0):

Use this way

```
if (data?.length <= 0) {
//any code
}
```

Comment: i also encounter different errors every time I refresh the page.

Comment: Hi @Berke Özbek,
So how can I help you?

Comment: Can you provide more code?

Comment: I add more code

Answer (score 0):

It's throwing that error because there is no data length to read.

Try this instead:

```
if (!data.length) {
      return null
}
```

Comment: i also encounter different errors every time I refresh the page.

Comment: @BerkeÖzbek what is the other errors?

Comment: @BerkeÖzbek can you wrap it in another if statement to check the length?

Comment: Even if I fix it in the local files of next js, there are always parts that give errors

Comment: @BerkeÖzbek my advice would be to debug/fix all local errors then see what your left with and ask a new question if you can't solve it.

Comment: Could it be due to a version error?

Comment: @BerkeÖzbek no not with that error.